# Combining and Compressing multiple JavaScript files in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jscompress

I am working on a PHP app that requires eight javascript files (hello web2.0).

I am wondering what the best way combine and compress all of the files dynamically.
Am I phrasing the question correctly?

The end result is that I would include one .js file in the header, and that .js file would include of the .js files in my "includes/js" directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a 2012 answer to this question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [jsmin-php](http://code.google.com/p/jsmin-php/)

Their sample code is:

```
require 'jsmin-1.1.1.php';

// Output a minified version of example.js.
echo JSMin::minify(file_get_contents('example.js'));
```

You may easily join several js files by doing something like:

```
require 'jsmin-1.1.1.php';

// Output a minified version of example.js.
echo JSMin::minify(file_get_contents('example.js') . file_get_contents('example2.js'));
```

Comment: would you recommend this over using Minify?

Comment: Both use jsmin to compress the Javascript files. Maybe you should compress your js files with both libraries and decide. The caching feature of Minify seems good, though.

Comment: It appears to be unmaintained with some outstanding issues

Comment: Is there a 2013 version of this answer?

Answer (score 7):

I've used [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) with my jQuery/PHP projects with lots of success.  It includes caching too so there isn't much overhead.

I ended up changing things around and using .htaccess to route all requests to my javascript folder to the minify script, so for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js,js/jquery-levitip.js,js/jquery-facebox.js,js/datepicker.js,js/ga.js"></script>
```

with my front-end HTML routes into my minify script and it returns all those scripts as one, compressed and minified.  That way I can define the includes normally and everything happens behind the scenes.

But anyway check the [user guide](http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/UserGuide) on their site, it's very well documented, and you should be able to pull things off the way you want too.  Oh and it works for CSS too.

Comment: my minify cache folder is always empty, so I am not sure is caching working

Answer (score 2):

You maybe could use [Yahoo JavaScript Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) which is a command line tool you could start from you PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PHP Speedy](http://phpspeedy.com)This will combine and compress your JS Files for you into 1 single file. It will also compress your HTML and CSS and your page will load a lot faster.

Answer (score -2):

```
 function compress($buffer) {
        /* remove comments */
        $buffer = preg_replace("/((?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:\/\/.*))/", "", $buffer);
        /* remove tabs, spaces, newlines, etc. */
        $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\t","\n",'  ','    ','     '), '', $buffer);
        /* remove other spaces before/after ) */
        $buffer = preg_replace(array('(( )+\))','(\)( )+)'), ')', $buffer);
        return $buffer;
    }
```

Source: http://castlesblog.com/2010/august/14/php-javascript-css-minification